# Shopping Cart Price Rule that excludes products on special

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I'm trying to create a Discount coupon that won't reduce the price of products already on sale. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: By "products already on sale" you mean...?

Comment: Products that have a Special Price set.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Admin > Catalog > Manage Attributes:

- Edit special_price attribute, setting "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to "Yes"

Add special_price = 0 condition to your coupon logic (test this of course).

Comment: I know it's an old question but do you know if catalog price rule set special_price? I tested your suggestion regarding my issue (http://stackoverflow.com/q/11718504/281258) but no luck.

Comment: Price rules will *not* set this at the database level.

Comment: This doesn't work if you use scheduled sales since your special price won't be 0 but it will no longer be on sale.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone still trying to figure this out as I was, this is the answer:

First change the special price attribute as benmarks advises above.

Go to your price rule, under the actions menu find the section "Apply the rule only to basket items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)"

Set the conditions to

If **ALL**  of these conditions are **FALSE** :

Special Price  **equals or greater than**  0.01

this way the discount is applied only to the products that are NOT on special. I found that every other way threw an error when there was a mixture of special price and full price products in the basket.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution have some false positives? For example, what if the special price is set, but the product is not currently being sold at full-price (because of "Special price (to|from) date")
Edit: Just saw that the OP did say "Products that have a Special Price set", but understand that this is not the same as "already discounted"

Answer (score 2):

This may be an older post but I just went through the same process in Magento 1.9.3.2 and here is how I was able to apply a promo code to all items excluding sale/special price items:

---

**Manage Attributes**:

Set change special_price attribute to "Yes" for "Use for Promo Rule Conditions"

**"Rules" under "Actions" tab in Shopping Cart Rules**:

If **ALL**  of these conditions are **FALSE** :

Attribute " Special Price " **is not assigned**
   Special Price  **equals or greater than  0.01**

---

Hope this helps!