# Catalog price rule vs Shopping cart rule

Tags: magento

I haven't found an answer anywhere so maybe some of you can came up with an explanation.

Here is the problem:
I have a catalog price rule. Discount of 10% on a category which applies on customer groups with 5% and 10% discount and of course normal customers.

Now, the problem is that when a customer that belong to a discount group buy a product from discounted category, the product already discounted have the discount group also. (5 or 10%).

Is there a way in telling magento to disable shopping cart rule if there is a discounted product in the cart?

I'm sorry I don't have a question related to some magento code but this is a big problem and any help is more than welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question looking for the same solution: The requirement is that customers in group X get 10% discount, but exclude products that already have discount, either via catalog price rules of special_price value.

There seems to be no clear cut solution, until now ;)
As noted in other answers, and comments, you can exclude products from the discount rule using a category.

This is a viable solution, but the issue is the need to maintain that list of products, which can be a very time-consuming, and error-prone task.

**It can be automated!**

Using the [Dynamic Category Products](http://www.proxiblue.com.au/premium-modules/magento-dynamic-category-products.html) extension (developed by myself), you can automate the list of products that has active discounts applied.

A quick howto.

In your store, create a new Root Category. 
This is simply to group your 'data' categories outside the default store view, so they don't accidentally show up anywhere.

you then create sub-categories from this new root category. One of those will be a category that will list all the products on discount.

As an example, here is my `Root Data Category`, with some sub-categories. I use these all in shopping cart rules.

[image]

For this answer, we would be interested in the `All products with discount applied`

This category contains Dynamic Rules as follows:

[image]

The category will be dynamic, self updating, daily, and can be used to exclude products from existing Shopping Cart Discounts.

I hope this is of help to someone.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a condition to the Shopping Cart Rule that the discounted products or categories are *not* included in the cart.  That would invalidate the cart rule in the event that they already had those discounted products in their cart.

Comment: Catalog price rule don't set special_price on products. Just modify the price in an observer so there is no condition that I could add in shopping cart rule. Already tried.

Comment: What I mean is you could exclude the specific SKUs for the discounted products.  That's probably not the most flexible solution though b/c you would have to manually keep the list of SKUs in sync between the Cart Rule Condition and the Catalog Rule.

Comment: Nope, that's not a solution. I add entire categories with hundred of products to Catalog rule.

Comment: @Ovidiu, I believe you can exclude Categories, as opposed to SKUs, in the Cart Rule Condition as well?

Answer (score 1):

See answer here...
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-catalog-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them

> There are 2 types of price rules in Magento, Catalog and Shopping Cart
>   Price Rules. Catalog Rules are enacted on products before they are
>   added to the cart, while Shopping Cart Price Rules are applied in the
>   shopping cart.